# Потоки в цикле for. Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, циклы

Доброго времени суток !

Есть код:

```
for (int zoomLvl = 0; zoomLvl <= ImageZoomQuantity; zoomLvl++) {

    // некий код, из которого я получаю изображение

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            // каждая итерация возвращает поделенную часть от изображения, которое получил выше 
        }

    }
}
```

Из первого цикла я получаю изображение а во втором и третьем цикле я это изображение делю на части. Я хочу из каждой итерации первого цикла сделать поток.

Есть ли способ разбить цикл `for` на потоки ? И хорошая ли это идея ?

Answer (score 1):

Немного переделанный вид, но та же логика. submit() возвращает Future, который можно будет использовать в будущем (при необходимости). (Содержит Java 8 код).

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
for (Image image : images) {
    executor.submit(() -> {
        Image subImage = // code to process image
        return subImage;
    });
}
```

Все зависит от того, для чего потом используются части оригинального изображения. В большинстве случаев, это можно также сделать в том же потоке, который разбил картинку. Это всего лишь из многих примеров разделения логики на потоки. Например, если вы используете GUI, то код будет немного другой (SwingWorker, Task, AsyncTask, в зависимости от фреймворка).
Насчет хорошая ли идея, если есть необходимость в более быстрой обработке ваших частей изображения, то потоки ускорят этот процесс. Если же программа уже работает и скорость достаточная для главного ее использования, то нет особой необходимости что-то менять.

Comment: Собвстенно для ускорения я это и затеял. 
Части оригинального изображения я делаю на квадраты во втором цикле (в комментариях указал). 
Я очень плохо разбираюсь в этой теме ( Она для меня новая. Везде простые примеры (я их понимаю) а как переделать свой код не очень. Посоветуете может с чего начать ? Что прочитать можно ?

Comment: В таком случае, потоки действительно ускорят работу вашей программы. Вам остается только адаптировать алгоритм для выполнения в нескольких потоках

Comment: не утрудит Вас зайти в чат ?

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю русскоязычных ресурсов. Вот один из лучших - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html. Насчет чата, можете приглашать

Comment: [Перейдите вот сюда !](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26853/)